# Robotframework test cases fails in JENKINS when we try to run on ChromeBrowser

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, robotframework

We are facing an issue like when running ROBOTFRAMEWORK Testcases from my local(Windows) machine chrome Browser is launched my testcases execution pass and through Jenkins 
Chrome browser is not opened but my Testcases are running in the Background.

But When I Run my TestCases on Remote Desktop(Windows) in Jenkins it doesn't open Chrome Browser and My Test Cases also Fails.but works fine from cmd.I tried downgrading the chrome version dint work.

The error I'm getting is:

```
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.107) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

| FAIL | TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.107)

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

Comment: Do you get errors? If so, what are they? Is jenkins running as a service on the windows machine? It can't run as a service because it needs access to the display.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins on Windows server runs as Windows server. Try setting up a slave node which is running as Java process, that can handle Chrome runs well. I have set up two Jenkins services on our test server and set Chrome tests to run always on the mock slave process (mock, while slave is actually on the same machine than master). When you set up the node choose 'Launch method: Launch Slave agents via Java Web Start'. Don't forget to make sure also the Java process is waking up after system restart, so your scheduled test runs have slave available at all times like master node is.